# Issue with data when created by loop

Tags: jquery, each

I'm using a [**plugin**](https://github.com/sdrdis/jquery.flowchart) that creates input and outputs on elements.

The normal output options are configured as follows:

```
outputs: {
    output_0: {
     label: '0',
     id: 'site0_0',
    },
    output_1: {
     label: '1',
     id: 'site1_1',
    },
    output_2: {
     label: '2',
     id: 'site2_2',
    },
}
```

When this is statically written in my script as above it works fine.

I'm now trying to dynamically create this list using a loop:

```
$(site).each(function(i, option) {
    sites += "output_" + option + ": { label: '" + option + "', id: 'site" + option + "_" + id + "',},"
})
```

This produces the same data as the staically set version above : (although the layout isn't as neat )

```
output_0: {
 label: '0',
 id: 'site0_0',
},
output_1: {
 label: '1',
 id: 'site1_1',
},
output_2: {
 label: '2',
 id: 'site2_2',
},
```

But when I try to add it as follows I get lots of errors :

```
outputs: {
    sites
}

jquery.flowchart.js?1565088567:545 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._createSubConnector (jquery.flowchart.js?1565088567:545)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._createSubConnector (jquery-ui.min.js?1565088567:6)
    at addConnector (jquery.flowchart.js?1565088567:516)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._getOperatorFullElement (jquery.flowchart.js?1565088567:527)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>._getOperatorFullElement (jquery-ui.min.js?1565088567:6)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>.createOperator (jquery.flowchart.js?1565088567:583)
    at e.<computed>.<computed>.createOperator (jquery-ui.min.js?1565088567:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js?1565088567:6)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.2.min.js?1565088567:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.2.min.js?1565088567:2)
```

The line 545 shows:

```
    $operator_connector_label.html(connectorInfos.label.replace('(:i)', subConnector + 1));
```

is it possible to create this data in a loop, and if it is how ?

Thanks

Comment: Check the typeof `sites`. It'll be string IMO, whereas your plugin is excepting a object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't supply an object property to a parent object as a string value in the manner you're attempting.

To fix this, create the child objects within the loop, like this:

```
var obj = {};

$(site).each(function(i, option) {
  obj['output_' + option] = {
    label: option,
    id: 'site' + option + '_' + id
  }
});

// in settings of the plugin:
outputs: obj
```

I'd also suggest not creating a jQuery object from `sites` if it's not an Element, or array of Element objects. From the context it appears to just be a plain array of strings, so a basic `for()` or `forEach()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks this make sense, but the result is the same. I've tried applying it as `outputs: { obj }` and `outputs: obj`  But I get the same error message.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assume `outputs` is the name of the property in the settings object of a plugin? If so I've amended the answer for you. Hopefully it helps

Comment: Thanks - just realized that.. all sorted :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped